# How to reduce tensorflow size for android?

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am trying to use TensorFlow in my android app. But the .so file is little bit larger than needed, is there a way to reduce libtensorflow_inference.so size?

Link [TensorFlow-Android-Inference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/cmake)

Answer (score 5):

There's no good guide to doing this yet, but you can start by removing unneeded ops using the print_selective_registration_header script:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/print_selective_registration_header.py

This needs to be documented more extensively.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if you do so.
Also what about the protobuf? Is there a way to cut out unused protobuf codes?

Comment: Hi, I generated ops_to_register.h and added -DSELECTIVE_REGISTRATION and flag into https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/cmake/CMakeLists.txt also added ops_to_register.h into includes. But it didn't affect .so's size.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to selective registration, you can try passing `-c opt` to bazel. For me this takes the uncompressed .so size from 24mb -> 13mb, and compressed from 5.5mb -> 4.4mb.

Comment: I am not using bazel, should I put this flag into https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/cmake/CMakeLists.txt ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to divide your apk to reduce apk size. [Check this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I want to reduce .so library file size

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to reduce the size of the .so files, but there is a way to save huge amounts of space by making it possible to compress the TensorFlow model.  See [this excellent blog post by Pete Warden](https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/) for more details.

In summary, you can use `optimize_for_inference` and `quantize_graph` to make it possible to compress a 87MB model to 24MB (you'll see this space saving when building the APK).