# how to reduce the size of the tensorflow android demo app?

Tags: tensorflow

I used the bazel command and built the tensorflow android demo app, the apk is 149MB. Is there any build options available to reduce the size of the apk?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400873/how-to-reduce-tensorflow-size-for-android) for general help on reducing tensorflow android size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any build options that will help (other than perhaps `bazel build -c opt`) but I noticed the APK contains two identical 50MB copies of tensorflow_inception_graph.pb. One is uncompressed (located in the APK at assets/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb) and one is compressed (located at the top level of a nested zip file called assets/inception5h.zip inside the APK).

Answer (score 0):

You should try performing quantization to reduce the size of the model. TensorFlow has a special tool called **Graph Transform** to do this. You can read more [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms).

For example, this is what I do to quantize my model:

```
/home/kwotsin/tensorflow-android/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
--in_graph=./frozen_model_mobilenet.pb \
--out_graph=./quantized_model_mobilenet.pb \
--inputs='Placeholder_only' \
--outputs='MobileNet/Predictions/Softmax' \
--transforms='
  add_default_attributes
  strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,299,299,3")
  remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)
  fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)
  fold_batch_norms
  fold_old_batch_norms
  quantize_weights
  quantize_nodes
  strip_unused_nodes
  sort_by_execution_order'
```

Using this, I reduced the model size to around one quarter of the frozen model.

One important thing you should take note is to clear the unnecessary graphs/files in your assets folder before building. I once did not clear the older files and continued to build my APK until the file size was too big (over 200+MB, which is weird), until I realized it was because I was stacking up files in the assets folder.

Comment: what does `strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,299,299,3")` do?